# How to make a tooltip appear immediately in Silverlight?

Tags: wpf, silverlight, tooltip, user-experience

In **WPF**, I get a tooltip to appear **immediately** like this:

```
TextBlock tb = new TextBlock();
tb.Text = name;
ToolTip tt = new ToolTip();
tt.Content = "This is some info on " + name + ".";
tb.ToolTip = tt;
tt.Cursor = Cursors.Help;
ToolTipService.SetInitialShowDelay(tb, 0);
```

This makes the user experience **better** since if the user wants to look at the tooltips of **five** items on the page, he doesn't have to wait that **long** second for each one.

**But since Silverlight does not have SetInitialShowDelay, what is a workaround to make the tooltip appear immediately?**

Comment: You will need to override styles of TextBlock and Tooltip, and you might some information there, in any of style, there will be Visual State Group with some delay in changing the visibility of tooltip, you can try customizing there.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to hook the MouseEnter event and show it straight away yourself:-

```
    TextBlock tb = new TextBlock(); 
    tb.Text = name; 
    ToolTip tt = new ToolTip(); 
    tt.Content = "This is some info on " + name + "."; 
    ToolTipService.SetToolTip(tb, tt);
    tb.MouseEnter += (s, args) => {  
      ((ToolTip)ToolTipService.GetToolTip((DependencyObject)s)).IsOpen = true;
    };
```

Comment: that's a good start, it works in general, but sometimes leaves the tooltip on the screen as a ghost, and the first mouseenter seems to not work, only the second time, will work with this

Answer (score 1):

Other than re-implementing the mouse enter (or the whole tooltip service), I'm afraid you might be out of luck - the delay you see is actually hard-coded into the "OnOwnerMouseEnter" method of the TooltipService:

(courtesy of Reflector)

```
    TimeSpan span = (TimeSpan) (DateTime.Now - _lastToolTipOpenedTime);
    if (TimeSpan.Compare(span, new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 100)) <= 0)
    {
        OpenAutomaticToolTip(null, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
    else
    {
        if (_openTimer == null)
        {
            _openTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
            _openTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(ToolTipService.OpenAutomaticToolTip);
        }
        _openTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 400);
        _openTimer.Start();
    }
```

Comment: It's ridiculous that this cannot be set with the normal methods available in WPF.